# js regexp for particular date format

Tags: javascript, regex

i just want to have a regexp for this string mm/dd/yyyy. Ex is 06/25/2016. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[0-1][0-9]\/[0-3][0-9]\/[0-9]{4,4}$
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/) is a good site to test your regex

Comment: No problem. If you navigate to my link and paste in the regex, you can see how the different character matches. I use it allways when I create Regexs

Answer (score 1):

THis should help

`[0-1][0-9]\/[0-3][0-9]\/[0-2][0-9]{3}`